# Parsing youtube with QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, parsing

I want to extract informations from youtube using Qt (QNetworkAccessManager). While the code below works with other websides, i dont get any data from youtube. Any idea what the configuration of QNetworkRequest should be?
PS. Yes i know i can achieve it by using YoutubeApi.

```
Youtube::Youtube(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
 
    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                     this, SLOT(readyRead(QNetworkReply*)));
}
 
 
 
void Youtube::makeRequest()
{
 
    qDebug() << "YOUTUBE::makeRequest()";
    request.setUrl(QUrl("www.youtube.com/"));
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyOwnBrowser 1.0");
    manager->get(request);
}
 
 
void Youtube::readyRead(QNetworkReply *replay)
{
    qDebug() << replay->readAll();
    QByteArray dataTemp = replay->readAll();
    website = dataTemp.toStdString();
 
}
```

Comment: Did you check `replay->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute)` as well as the returned headers?

Comment: qDebug() << replay->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute); returns "QVariant(Invalid)"

Comment: Did you check the `error` method as well?

Comment: errorString "Protocol \"\" is unknown"
error QNetworkReply::ProtocolUnknownError

Comment: @black_gay use `request.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/"));`

Comment: @eyllanesc and what shoud i use within QNetworkAccessManager to agree to stuff (accepting cookies) offered on this consent.youtube.com page, which now opens each time a non logged user opens a youtube link?

Comment: If you want to access that information then QNetworkAccessManager will not be the best option, it is just a client, instead use QWebEnginePage (or QWebEngineView) where if a session is created that can handle cookies, instead with QNAM you will have to implement all that behavior.

Comment: @eyllanesc QNAM can handle cookies. The issue is more about interacting with the page as QNAM does not handle HTML or JavaScript. If interaction with the page is needed QWebEnginePage is a solution, but page interactions have to be done with JavaScript. It is also possible to pass the cookie popup (or even login) in a normal browser (or in QWebEnginePage) and then copy the cookies from the browser and put them into the QNAM.

Comment: @BenjaminT Exactly, that's what I wanted to point out (maybe I was not clear about it), that is, I wanted to go a little further since as the OP points out, he wants to obtain information as if he were using the YT API.

Comment: @eyllanesc i managed to read the queried youtube page with request.setRawHeader("COOKIE" , "CONSENT=YES+42"   ); but it works only the first time, with the 2nd and next queries the QNetworkAccessManager returns the youtube consent page only, … any idea what to do?

Comment: A side note: wget seemingly succeeds in this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get info about a video and store in a QJsonDocument object:

```
    QNetworkAccessManager* net = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    net->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://noembed.com/embed? 
    url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")));

    connect(net, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,[](QNetworkReply* reply)
    {
        QString output = reply->readAll();
        QJsonDocument doc;
        QJsonParseError errorPtr;
        doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(output.toUtf8(), &errorPtr);

        if(! doc.isNull())
        {
            QJsonObject videoInfoJson = doc.object();
            qDebug() <<videoInfoJson.value("title").toString();
        }
    });
```